# How do i get rid of a line drawn by drawRect to disappear .05 seconds after the user touches the screen?

Tags: core-graphics, drawrect

I have the touchesBegan void before this which triggers this event,
but i need this line to show, wait for so many seconds, then disappear:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
      // Drawing code

//Make a simple rectangle and fill background BLUE with half Opeque
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//[[UIColor blueColor] set];
//CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
//rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 40);
//CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

//Make a simple RED line from 0,0 to 100, 100 in a FRAME
//CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
[[UIColor redColor] set];
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _spaceShip.center.x, _spaceShip.center.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint( context, nextLocX, nextLocY);
```

**CODE FOR MAKING THE LINE DISAPPEAR**

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Redraw the frame without that line would be the obvious solution.

Draw over it in the background color would be a less-pretty solution that might in some cases run faster.